# Managing transitive dependency versions in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

I have 3 gradle projects: Project-1, Project-2, Project-3. Project-1 and Project-2 are Java libraries, Project-3 is a consumer of these libraries. Both Project-1 and Project-2 have a dependency on Module-A. However, for every one of them I want to be able to specify a list of exact versions that they are compatible with. For example, Project-1 is compatible and tested with Module-A, versions 1 and 2, but Project-2 is compatible with Module-A, versions 2 and 3. I want to be able to specify these requirements in the build configuration of each project. These dependencies can be impelementation only or even compileOnly.

When Project-3 consumes libraries built by Project-1 and Project-2, I want to make sure that Module-A is resolved to the latest version that is explicitly listed in both Project-1 and Project-2. Otherwise, I would like to get an error at the build step, that no satisfying dependency resolution can be found. Ideally, I would like to be able to explicitly specify version of Module-A in Project-3 Gradle build and receive an error if it’s not compatible with any of Project-1 or Project-2.

Project-1 and Project-2 artifacts are consumed from and uploaded to a local Maven repository using Maven plugin.

Comment: what is the difference between a project and a module here?

Comment: @homerman the term module is often used in Gradle docs to describe dependency: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_terminology.html#sub:terminology_module

Comment: @homerman in my case use module as an external software vs project as something I have control over. But for Project-3 artifacts of Project-1 and Project-2 are external module dependencies as any others.

Comment: thanks. as an IntelliJ and Gradle user i often find myself second-guessing what people are talking about when they refer to a "project" and/or "module".

Answer (score 1):

see if the below approach helps. it assumes a project structured with three modules like so:

```
Top-level
├── Project-1
├── Project-2
└── Project-3
```

...and various versions of Guava assume the role of `Module-A` as you've described the setup.

**Top-level `build.gradle`**:

```
ext {
  project1GuavaVersions = ['26.0-jre','27.0-jre']
  project2GuavaVersions = ['25.0-jre','26.0-jre']

  if(project1GuavaVersions.disjoint(project2GuavaVersions)) {
    throw new GradleException('No common version(s) of Guava defined')
  } else {
    project3GuavaVersion = new HashSet(project1GuavaVersions + project2GuavaVersions).max()
  }

subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
}
```

extra properties used to specify acceptable versions of Guava for each module. Project-3's version is calculated as the latest version used between Project-1 and Project-2. (additionally, the Java plugin is applied to the three sub-projects for convenience).

**Project-1's `build.gradle`**:

```
archivesBaseName = 'project1'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation "com.google.guava:guava:[${project1GuavaVersions.join(',')}]"
}
```

the extra property for Project-1's Guava versions is interpolated and transformed from a list of strings to a comma-delimited string. this uses Gradle's ability to use Ivy notation for specifying a range of versions, ie `[26.0-jre,27.0-jre]`.

**Project-2's `build.gradle`**:

```
archivesBaseName = 'project2'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation "com.google.guava:guava:[${project2GuavaVersions.join(',')}]"
}
```

(similar implementation to Project-1)

**Project-3's `build.gradle`**:

```
archivesBaseName = 'project3'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation project(':project1')
  implementation project(':project2')
  implementation "com.google.guava:guava:$project3GuavaVersion"
}
```

Project-1 and Project-2 are defined as project-level dependencies, and the explicitly calculated version for Guava defined as an extra property is used here.

i hope that covers everything. if nothing else, i hope it inspires some new thought!

**UPDATE**

as you've mentioned in the comments that your projects are not setup hierarchically, you also have the option of setting them up in a "flat" arrangement in which all the projects exist at the same folder depth, like so:

```
(root)
├── project1
│   └── build.gradle
├── project2
│   └── build.gradle
├── project3
│   └── build.gradle
└── master
    ├── build.gradle
    └── settings.gradle
```

"master" here is a specially named project that sits alongside the other projects. `settings.gradle` should be moved into `master` and should use `Settings.includeFlat()` to indicate that you want to include projects that exist as the same level:

```
includeFlat 'project1'
includeFlat 'project2'
includeFlat 'project3'
```

the details of my originally proposed solution should be applicable to this setup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, this set up does not achieve what I need: if `project1GuavaVersions = ['27.0-jre','28.0-jre']`, I want the build of `project3` to fail, as there is no common version that can satisfy all the dependencies.

Comment: i've updated the snippet in the "top-level" build file to address that

Comment: In my set up there is no top-level build. All there projects are built independently.

Comment: i've updated my post with details on a "flat" project structure